# Empty logs a C# Rest WebService

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, logging, log4net

I Have A  C# Rest webService which working fine.
I needed to add logs using the log4net .
It's working in DEV/Staging environnements but not in production.
I Have granted the Application pool & all the user of machine the required rights on my logs folder but still cannot see the logs.
I'am using 4.5.2 framework ,Windows 2012 R2 as a hosting environement

My web.conf

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="F:\logs\WebService\ManageParty\%property{LogName}_%date{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger{1} %property{LogName} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="*****.WS.ManageParty" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

[image]

Comment: Please describe more details about your Dotnet version, Web-Service framework,  and hosting environment. Please fix the question, the image can not be seen.

Comment: Test it with (Everyone granted permission) for a test in some minutes. Double-check minimum log level (Set it to Debug for a test)